# MySQL and skipping WHERE predicate

Tags: mysql

If last_name below is NULL, will it skip the WHERE comparison on that column to increase performance?

```
AND (last_name IS NULL OR sp.last_name LIKE CONCAT('%',IFNULL(last_name, ''),'%'))
```

Comment: This is called "short-circuit" evaluation. You'll find more results if you search on that.

Comment: I ran some tests which may be of interest, results in my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL is free to perform the comparisons in either order.

Most likely it will do the `NULL` check first because it is faster to compute, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: If it does by chance pick the NULL one, it would skip the second comparison correct?

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you actually tried the more simple `WHERE sp.last_name LIKE CONCAT('%',last_name,'%'))` that you seem to be avoiding? It *might* turn out that it's not as slow as you feared...

Comment: I have and there is a slight increase in query time.

Comment: @MikeFlynn, according to tests (it's not documented) MySQL does perform short-circuit evaluation, but as Mark explained, this is done after it's been through the optimizer, which will perform the evaluation in the order it decides, and the order may change (eg. it could be any order).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that is true, it will include the row without evaluating the latter expression. However, this could (should?) be tested with a known dataset by having the latter expression create side effects (such as incrementing a counter) and inspecting the counter before and after it is run against a data set with only NULL in last_name column.

## edit: Tested v5.5.25

For the curious:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| NULL |
+------+
| Bill |
+------+
```

Each query below is preceded by `set @foo=0;`, and then the results of `select @foo;` are shown.

```
SELECT name FROM names WHERE (@foo:=@foo+1 OR name IS NULL);
-- 1 (did optimize) - same without parenthesis

SELECT name FROM names WHERE name IS NULL OR (@foo:=@foo+1);
-- 1 (did optimize)

SELECT name FROM names WHERE (@foo:=@foo+1) OR name IS NULL;
-- 2 (did not optimize)
```

Interestingly, I could not produce an update query which was not optimized this way. i.e. no matter how I arranged the two expressions in the where clause, it *always* only incremented @foo once.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
AND  (if(last_name is null,1, sp.last_name 
LIKE CONCAT('%',last_name,'%')))
```

Comment: Isn't the `last_name IS NULL OR ...` superfluous here?

Comment: I mean unnecessarily redundant and needlessly repetitive.

Comment: I agree isn't that redundant?

Comment: I guess so, I just took the important part of your code, after the OR is the important thing to fix. I just remove that part

Comment: I just tried this, and it actually increased the time.  I was getting 1.17 seconds on average and this booted it up to 1.2 seconds.

Comment: I changed it after you told me about the time. now it should be faster that 1.2 sec

Comment: It did improve, but its around the same as my original query.  What was actually changed in this one?  The removal of IFNULL?

Comment: I was using 2 `if`, the second was not necesary

Comment: This is cleaner but doesn't look to improve the performance on the query but is equal to the original.  I would use this going forward on my queries.

Comment: The perfomance is going to be really hard to improve it if you are using `LIKE` because even if you create a full text index, it will be ignore